# Is Gradient really the direction of steepest ascent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to intuitively understand why the gradient gives you the direction of the **steepest** ascent of a function.

Apart from the already posted questions, my confusion arises from the fact that we form the gradient vector from the derivative of each dimension **separately**. Then take the vector consisting of both (for 2D) derivatives take it as the steepest ascent.

What if in both directions the derivative is say $5$, so our vector will be $45$ degrees from both axis, But in that direction specifically the function goes down ?

If it's not clear what I'm confused with, consider this function represented as an image :

$$ \begin{pmatrix}100&5&-100\\0&\textit{0}&5\\0& 0&   0\end{pmatrix}$$

at *0*, it makes sense that the derivative is $5$ in $x$ and in $y$, but a vector of $(5,5)$ goes to a direction that's not a steepest ascent. Does this have to do with the differentiability of the function ? what am I missing ?

Comment: That function you've given is not differentiable, and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing the values inbetween 0, 5, and -100. Somewhere there is a level set connecting the two values of 5. So when you leave 0 in the direction (5,5), first you come to that level set. In other words, consider the function $\sin(x \pi)$. If you sample it at the integer values of $x$, to obtain an image as you say, you will only see a constant function zero. Or, if you actually mean a piecewise constant function, then it is not differentiable as the above comment says.

Comment: To be differentiable means to be almost flat. Can you see how gradient works on a plane? It's the same for all differentiable functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is gradient the direction of steepest ascent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What will help your intuition the most is remembering that the derivative (the gradient) is a local feature, it only depends on what the function is *at that point*, and not any distance away.

You may be visualizing a function which buckles down in the gradient direction, so it's not the steepest ascent some distance away -- but at the point where you find the tangent plane it is the steepest ascent for at least a very small distance.

At a point where a function is differentiable, the function is almost planar in a very, very small region around that point.  Remember to visualize the local region as nearly a plane, and your intuition will be happier with the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the relationship between the gradient $\nabla f(p)$ and the directional derivative $df(p) \textbf{u}$ in the direction of a unit vector $\textbf{u}$:
$$df(p) \textbf{u} = \nabla f(p) \cdot \textbf{u}$$
Since
$$\nabla f(p) \cdot \textbf{u} = ||\nabla f(p)|| \cos \theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f(p)$ and $\textbf{u}$, the unit vector which maximizes the directional derivative is clearly the one whose angle against $\nabla f(p)$ has cosine $1$, an this is $\theta = 0$.

The place where this geometric intuition collides with the phenomenon that you worry about is at the beginning: why are the partial derivatives, i.e. the directional derivatives in just two directions, enough to determine the directional derivatives in *all* directions?  The answer is: they aren't.  An unmentioned hypothesis in what I wrote above is that the gradient is continuous at $p$, and without continuity the behavior you describe is actually possible.  Here's an example.

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}$.  First, let us calculate $f_x(0,0)$ by taking the derivative of the function $f(t,0)$ at $t=0$:
$$f_x(0,0) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \frac{0}{t^2} = 0$$
Similarly, $f_y(0,0) = 0$.  Now let us calculate the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the vector $\textbf{v} = (1,1)$:
$$df(0,0) \textbf{v} = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} f(t,t) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \frac{t^3}{2t^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
So indeed, this function exhibits the sort of behavior you describe, though you can calculate that the partial derivatives of this function are not continuous at $(0,0)$.

In fact, even worse behavior is possible: there is a function whose directional derivative exists and is zero in every direction but which has nonzero derivative along the parabola $(t,t^2)$.  But all of this pathology is eliminated if the partial derivatives are continuous.  It is worthwhile to study the proof of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a first order Taylor's approximation of a continuously differential function $f:U \to \mathbb{R}, U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x$ as follows:

$f(x+d)\approx f(x)+\nabla f(x)^\top d$, i.e. $f$ takes a small step in the direction $d$ at the point $x$. So, a normalized steepest descent can be defined as follows:

$\Delta x = argmin\{\nabla f(x)^\top d | \|d\|=1\}=-argmax\{\nabla f(x)^\top d | \|d\|=1\}=- d^*.$

Geometrical visualization of the steepest descent direction (with an example of  $\ell _2 -$ norm) is as follows:
[image]
[image]