# Why is gradient describe the steepest ascent direction and not the steepest descent

Tags: gradient-descent

I have checked all over the internet and I cannot find why is gradient shows you the steepest ascent and not the steepest descent

How can we proof that?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/223265/43760

Answer (score 3):

The directional derivative of function $f$ at point $a$ along vector $\bf v$ is ${\bf v} \cdot {\nabla f(a)}$.  So if ${\bf v} = \nabla f(a)$, we get $(\nabla f(a)) \cdot (\nabla f(a))$.  But the dot product of any vector with itself $\ge 0$.  Therefore it's ascent, not descent.