# Gradient vs Gradient Ascent?

Tags: vector-analysis, regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

We say Gradient is always increasing and gradient ascent maximizes the values, then can i say that **gradient and gradient ascent** terms can be used interchangeably

Comment: Do you mean "the gradient always points in the direction of greatest increase?" In any case, the two terms are not interchangeable, as the gradient refers to a function and gradient ascent refers to an algorithm.

Comment: No. The gradient is a *derivative*. Gradient ascent is a *dynamical system*, a *numerical algorithm*.

Comment: As far as I get it from other sources Derivative is a scalar quantity while gradient is a vector where the no. of independent variables are more then one. From this the definition i get is as follows: At any given point it tells you the direction in which the function changes with the greatest rate

Answer (score 3):

Your comment seems to be correct. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function.

The **gradient** of $f$ is given by:
$$ \nabla f = (\partial_{x_1}f,\ldots,\partial_{x_n}f)$$
which is a *vector field* (i.e. vector function) $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. So, at every point $\vec{x}$, the gradient at that point $\nabla f(\;\!\vec{x}\;\!)$ is a vector that [points in the direction of greatest increase of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent?rq=1).

So, given a function $f$, the gradient gives a special set of vectors (one for each point in space), that everywhere points in the direction one should move if one wanted to increase $f$.
Notice that the gradient is just the regular derivative when $n=1$.

More correctly, I would say that the gradient is an *operator*, whose input is a function and whose output is a vector field, with this special property.

On the other hand, **gradient ascent** is an *algorithm for maximizing functions*. Suppose we have a set $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and we want $y\in D$ such that $f$ is maximal. So, given some function $f$, we want to find: $$ y=
\arg\max_{x\in D} f(x) $$
How can we do so? We use the special property of the gradient from before. If we want to maximize $f$, the smartest thing (ignoring local maxima) to do is *follow the direction of greatest increase of $f$* - which happens to be the direction specifed by the gradient. See [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Description), for example.

Summary: the gradient is a vector field associated to every function, while gradient ascent is an optimization algorithm that can find locations of extremas of a given function, which uses the special properties of the gradient field to work.