# A question about gradient direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

When I read proofs about the direction of gradient [Why is gradient the direction of steepest ascent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent), the top rated answer shows that the direction of grad$(f)$ should be the same as vector $v$ so that $f$ changes fastest along $v$ direction. However since $v$ is arbitrary I don't see why it is the direction for the maximum function increase. Also I was wondering why grad$(f)$ is the same direction as the normal vector instead of tangent vector. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: maybe this video will help:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEB2z7ZlRAw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is gradient the direction of steepest ascent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent)

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't understand the top rated answer and that's the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @Maskoff Then perhaps comment on the post and ask them to clarify?