# Proof of why gradient of F is the steepest ascent using the given method

Tags: vector-analysis

[The picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBokms.png)  shows two contour lines of a function $F(x,y)$. Now, the normal vector to the contour at point $A$ is the steepest ascent or decent ($\vec{ AC}$) for a fixed value of length $l$.
Now to prove the $\vec{AC} = c \times \nabla F(x,y)$ at point $A$, where $c$ is any real constant.
I need to prove $$\vec{AB} =  c \times \frac{\partial F}{\partial {x}} 
(i) \\ \text{and} \\ \vec{BC} = c \times \frac{\partial F}{\partial {y}}\text (j) .$$

So how do I prove that? Please help me prove it using this method.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent?rq=1

Comment: @Epiousios I have seen that already, thanks, but I needed help with figuring out this particular proof. –