# Gradient is both perpendicular to the curve but also direction of steepest ascent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble figuring out how the gradient (which seems to be the derivative in multiple variables) can be both the direction of steepest ascent AND the perpendicular vector to a surface.
Say we have a function = $v = x^{2} + y^{2}$

The gradient is is then $[2x, 2y]$

At point say -1, 1, the gradient is $[-2, 2]$. Does this mean that at point -1, 1, the direction of steepest ascent is the vector -2, 2?

IF so, that to me implies that the steepest ascent direction is also tangent to the curve $x^{2} + y^{2}$ in some way since it points in the direction of the curve. How can it also be perpendicular to the surface?

I'm obviously misunderstanding something but I need help in figuring out what.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223252

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable.

1. **Direction of steepest ascent**: we want to prove that among all directions (i.e. unitary vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$), the vector $\nabla f(x)/|\nabla f(x)|$ is the one that gives us the maximum value of the function $v\mapsto \nabla f(x) \cdot v$ (where $\cdot$ is the dot product). So, $\nabla f(x) \cdot v=|\nabla f(x)||v|\cos \theta(v)=|\nabla f(x)|\cos \theta(v)$, since $|v|=1$. Here $\cos \theta(v)$ is the angle of $v$ with the gradient. Hence we have a maximum when $\theta(v)=0$, so that $v$ must lie on the direction of gradient with the same orientation. So $v=c\nabla f(x)$, with $c>0$. Apply the norm on both sides and get $c=1/|\nabla f(x)|$ (assuming the gradient is not $0$).
2. **Orthogonality**: orthogonality is a bit tricky, how did you define it? Do you know what it means for a vector $v$ to be orthogonal to a surface, or a curve? In any case, the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is a $2$-dimensional vector, so he lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$, while the surface $\{x,f(x)\}$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^{2+1}$. The gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is orthogonal to the set $\{y|f(y)=f(x)\}$, which is (sometimes) a smooth curve. However, a proof requires a definition of orthogonality (or tangency).

---

We maximize $v\mapsto \nabla f(x) \cdot v$ because it's a (first order) approximation of $f(x+v)-f(x)$, which is what you call "ascent". It is a first order approximation since, by differentiability $f(x+v)=f(x)+\nabla f(x) \cdot v+$higher order terms.

We choose $|v|=1$ because it is a standard way of defining a "direction", but also because you can make $\nabla f(x) \cdot v$ as big as you want if you don't limit the norm $|v|$. Hence requiring $|v|=1$ is a way of making the problem "well-phrased".