# Determine the value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overrightarrow{u}}(1,1)$

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, curves

The following function represents a curve in a two-dimensional plane.
$$f(x,y)=x\arctan(\frac{x}{y})$$

Determine the value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overrightarrow{u}}(1,1)$, where $u$ points to the direction of maximum growth for the function at the given point.

I'm trying to understand this problem, but I really don't know what I should do to solve it.
I would like to know your opinions and possible solutions regarding this exercise. What results should I use to solve it and how should I proceed to find its solution? How can I interpret it geometrically?

Comment: Do you know of basic properties of the gradient?

Comment: [Why is the gradient the direction of the steepest ascent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223252/721644)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f(x,y)=x\arctan(x/y)$ is differentiable function at $(x_{0},y_{0}):=(-1,1)$, then $$\max_{|\|\vec{u}\|=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{u}}(x_{0},y_{0})=\|\nabla f(x_{0},y_{0})\|$$
i.e., the maximum of the directional derivative occurs when $\vec{u}$ has the same direction as the gradient vector $\nabla f$.

- The gradient vector $\nabla f$ can be find as $\nabla f=(f_{x},f_{y})$ and the norm of gradient vector in the plane can be find $\|\nabla f\|=\sqrt{f_{x}^{2}+f_{y}^{2}}$.